# paypal IPN not sending any notification

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have integrated paypal with my website and but it does take the payment but it doesnot send any IPN to my php file which should update my databse....
there is the code I have been using:
 to call

```
session_start();
if($mode=='live')
{
    $url=" https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    $email="nnnnnnn_singh@live.com";
    $_SESSION['url']=$url;
    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
    $_SESSION['subtotal']=$subtotal;
}
else if($mode=='sandbox')
{
    $url= "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    $email="nnnnnnn_1329707350_biz@gmail.com";
    $_SESSION['url']=$url;
    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
    $_SESSION['subtotal']=$subtotal;
}
?>

                <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="shopping cart"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $subtotal;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo SITE_URL."/shoppingCart.php" ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="php url" />
                <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $customer_ID;?>"/>
                <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"/>
                </form>
```

and php code

from php IPN  sample code.....

Comment: www.paypal.com > History > IPN History > What does this say? (Note: if you can't see 'IPN History', enable IPN first via Profile > My selling tools > Instant Payment Notification preferences.)

Answer (score 1):

Try:
1. login in your paypal account
2. go to profile --> History --> IPN history --> turn on my IPN
3. insert your IPN listener URL.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="php url" />
```

This shouldn't be on localhost, since PayPal sends POST data from its servers to that URL. So localhost won't work.

Comment: Yes I have been using the server url and I have used the code from the IPN sample code in the url that has been called but no luck

Comment: See my earlier comment. What's in the IPN history? What's the status of all messages?